# Undefined CSS File in a play2 project

Tags: angularjs, scala, model-view-controller, web, playframework

I have downloaded `angularjs eclipse` plugin from market place in my `eclipse kepler`. I imported the maven project whose packaging is `play2` and converted it to angularjs project but then it is showing following errors:

**index.scala.html:**

[image]

**The error message:**

```
Undefined CSS file
```

**Directory Structure:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the /target/scala-{ver}/src_managed folder to the classpath should clear Eclipse from errors.

The **routes** object that your view is referring is generated during compilation and placed under the `target/scala-{ver}/src_managed` directory. From what can be seen in the attached picture, the target directory is empty.